# How to solve dyld: Library not loaded on MacOS?

Tags: intel, dyld, instruction-set

I will do some experiments with X86 ISA by using PIN Binary Instrumentation Tool. I downloaded the tool from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-binary-instrumentation-tool-downloads .

You can see the ./pin file. However, when I try to run `./pin` command from terminal, I am getting below error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: ./libxed.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mahsunaltin/Documents/University/Computer Organization/P2/pin-3.10-97971-gc5e41af74-clang-mac/intel64/bin/pinbin
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath ./libxed.dylib in /Users/mahsunaltin/Documents/University/Computer Organization/P2/pin-3.10-97971-gc5e41af74-clang-mac/intel64/bin/pinbin with restricted binary
Abort trap: 6
```

Is there anyone who know how I can solve this problem?

NOTE: I have MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 1):

The PIN team is aware of this issue and are currently working to solve it.
The current fix is to disable SIP on your Mac machine.
Note that disabling SIP is the only way to run Pin on system files.
More information about SIP can be found here:
https://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection

PS: The PIN group discussion regarding this: https://groups.io/g/pinheads/topic/73287901#13117